# PIC- Analog Digital Converter ( MPLAB - C )

Tags: adc, pic, c, delay, mplabx

I had a problem with some code where I had to convert analog to digital using my PIC24HJ128GP506A microcontroller. As you may know, the microcontroller uses Successive Approximation for conversion, but I often got incorrect results.

After I implemented a small delay code, it solved my problem. However, I would like to understand: Why did the delay resolve the issue?

Code without Delay:

```c
float readADC(unsigned int pin)
{
    _CH0SA = pin; 
    unsigned long tmpvalue = 0;
    float result = 0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){   
        AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 1;    
        while (!AD1CON1bits.DONE); // Wait samp  
        AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 0;
        tmpvalue = tmpvalue + ADC1BUF0;
    }  

    result = tmpvalue / 50;   
    return result ;        
}
```

With delay :

```c
float readADC(unsigned int pin)
{  
    _CH0SA = pin; 
    unsigned long tmpvalue = 0;
    float result = 0; 
  
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){ 
        AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 1;    
        while (!AD1CON1bits.DONE); // Wait samp
        AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 0;
        tmpvalue = tmpvalue + ADC1BUF0;
        for(long i = 4500;i>0;i--);      // My delay
    }

    result = tmpvalue / 50;
    return result ;        
}
```

```c
void configADC(void){  
    // AD1CON1
    _ADON = 0;
    _AD12B = 1;
    _FORM = 0;
    _SSRC = 7;
    _ASAM = 1; 
    _ADON = 1;

    // AD1CON2
    _VCFG = 0;  
    _SMPI = 0;

    //AD1CON3
    _ADRC = 1;  
    _SAMC = 4;  
    //AD1CHS0
    _CH0NA = 0;
    //_CH0SA = 0; 
    //INTERRUPT
    _NSTDIS = 1; 
    _AD1IF  = 0;  
    _AD1IE  = 0; 
    _AD1IP  = 2;  
}
```

Comment: btw    this:`result = tmpvalue / 50;`is an pure integer conversion. You need a cast to `float`

Comment: Have you switched `ADCON1`to auto conversion? Show your ADC init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably the set-up time for the ADC.  From the data sheet:
[image]

It is possible that you could have a significant number of "indeterminate" readings during the 20 microseconds required to stabilize the ADC module.  I would try adding a delay before your first reading, and then try reducing the time between reads and see if that helps.